# What are the algebras for the codensity monad of $\textbf{FP-Ring} \rightarrow \textbf{Ring}$

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, monads

Let $\textbf{Fin-Set}$ denote the category of finite sets, and let $\textbf{Set}$ denote the category of sets. The inclusion functor $\textbf{Fin-Set} \rightarrow \textbf{Set}$ from the category of finite sets has as its codensity monad the ultrafilter monad.

Let $k$ be a field. Write $\textbf{Vect}$ for the category of vector spaces over $k$, and write $\textbf{Fin-Vect}$ for the category of finite dimensional vector spaces over $k$. The inclusion functor $\textbf{Fin-Vect} \rightarrow \textbf{Vect}$ has as its codensity monad the double dual monad. Algebras over this monad are linearly compact $k$-vector spaces. See Tom Leinster's question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104777/what-are-the-algebras-for-the-double-dualization-monad) for an interesting exposition of the question.

Let $\textbf{FP-Ring}$ be the category of finitely presented rings, and let $\textbf{Ring}$ be the category of rings. There is an embeding $\textbf{FP-Ring} \rightarrow \textbf{Ring}$.

> **Question:** What is the codensity monad for this functor? What are the algebras for this codensity monad?

**Notes:**

1. Finite sets are the compact objects in set, finite dimensional vector spaces are the compact objects in vector spaces, and finitely presented rings are the compact objects in rings.
2. Just as in the cited question, this will complete an analogy: sets are to compact hausdorff spaces, as vector spaces are to linearly compact vector spaces, as rings are to ?.

Comment: A remark: contrary to what happen in Set or Vect, many rings do not have maps to nonzero finitely presented rings. For example any $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ have none , all these ring will be sent to the $0$ ring by the codensity monad. So it is unlikely this monad is something well known... but maybe its algebras are nice...

Comment: Also, the main theorem (slide 14) of this (http://conferences.inf.ed.ac.uk/ct2019/slides/72.pdf) forthcoming paper cannot apply because the monoidal structure is far from being closed. This is a very delicate situation.

Comment: One thing to clarify: are these rings commutative? In another direction, in light of Simon Henry's comment, I think it might be fruitful to generalize and work with (finitely-presentable) algebras over some base ring rather than just over $\mathbb Z$. For instance, it might be easiest to start with the base ring being an algebraically closed field. Beyond that, there are all sorts of finiteness conditions coming from algebraic geometry which could be subtituted for "finitely presentable", and might be more interesting. For that matter, one could replace all rings with schemes...

Comment: If you're really interested in working over $\mathbb Z$, you might start by first figuring out what the codensity monad is for the inclusion of finitely-generated abelian groups into all abelian groups -- this is closer to the vector space example, but works over $\mathbb Z$.